# Determinar si una etiqueta <a> debe ser controlada por Angular o por el DOM

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript

Tengo un menú que funciona a medias, lo baje de un template que no tiene documentación, pero la solución parece sencilla.

**menu.component.html**

```
<div class="app-sidebar__inner">
  <ul class="vertical-nav-menu">
    <li class="app-sidebar__heading">Menu</li>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list" routerLinkActive="active">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length > 0" >
        <a href="">
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngIf="!item.children">
        <a [routerLink]="[ item.route ]">
      </ng-container>

        <i [class]="'metismenu-icon pe-7s-' + item.icon"></i>
        <span class="fs8">{{ item.name }}</span>
        <i *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length > 0" 
          class="metismenu-state-icon pe-7s-angle-down caret-left"></i>
      </a>
      <ul *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length > 0">
        <li *ngFor="let child of item.children">
          <a [routerLink]="[ item.route + child.route ]">
            <span class="fs7">{{ child.name }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Necesito identificar si la iteración del `ng-for` tiene un índice que se llame `children`entonces esa opción del menú se convierte en una opción desplegable que no debe llevar a ningún lado, únicamente hacer la animación de desplegar las rutas hijas. En caso que no haya el índice `children` entonces es una ruta que debe controlar Angular con `routerLink` por ende implementé este pequeño truco que no sirve

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length > 0" >
    <a href="">
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="!item.children">
    <a [routerLink]="[ item.route ]">
  </ng-container>
```

Y el error que marca es

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Unexpected closing tag "ng-container". It may happen when the tag has
>   already been closed by another tag. For more info see
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags

¿Qué me recomendarían hacer?

**menu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import HeaderList from '../interfaces/header-list.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.sass','../app.component.sass']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public list: Array<HeaderList> = [
    {
      icon: 'home',
      name: 'Página principal',
      route: '/'
    },
    {
      icon: 'cash',
      name: 'Cálculo de comisiones',
      route: '/calculo-comisiones'
    },
    {
      icon: 'config',
      name: 'Configuración layout',
      route: '/subir-layout'
    },
    {
      icon: 'cloud-upload',
      name: 'Carga layout',
      route: '/carga-layout'
    },
    {
      icon: 'safe',
      name: 'Aprovisionamiento',
      route: '/aprovisionamiento'
    },
    {
      icon: 'calculator',
      name: 'Comisiones',
      route: '/comisiones',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Autorización de comisiones',
          route: '/autorizacion-comisiones'
        },
        {
          name: 'Consulta de status comisiones',
          route: '/consulta-comisiones'
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: bueno el error viene por esta etiqueta que no esta cerrada `<a href="">` deberia `<a href=""></a>`

Comment: Si claro, pero es la única que tiene una modificación de atributo

Comment: Tal como dice hawks creo que te hace falta es cerrarlas, angular no compilara bien si hay errores en el html, la solución mas fácil es cerrarlas, entonces se solucionaria el error automáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos errores, el primero es que no estas cerrando las etiquetas `<a></a>` por lo tanto angular nunca va a compilar bien y siempre te saltara este error.

Lo segundo es que si estas usando `lazyLoad` que es lo mas seguro ya que es una excelente forma de manejar las rutas de angular, estas añadiendo mal las rutas:

La ruta la pones tu de la siguiente manera:

```
<a [routerLink]="[ item.route ]">
```

Lo cuál es incorrecto, yo en un proyecto de ionic que estoy desarrollando, lo tengo de la siguiente manera y me funciona (ionic funciona con angular):

```
[routerLink]="'/favourites'"
```

Por lo tanto en tu caso debe ser:

```
<a [routerLink]="item.route"></a>
```

Y para los children sería así:

```
<a [routerLink]="item.route + child.route"></a>
```